# Movie Identification: Sci fi film about a space crew that is really in an alien simulation

Tags: story-identification, movie

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide the name of this movie.  I will post as much as I can remember about it.

The premise was something like a crew is on a space mission from Earth and expect the trip to take a long time. Space madness starts to set in as things go wrong and one of the crew starts to suspect they are actually in a simulation.  The rest of the crew thinks he's crazy.

The crazy guy performs an experiment where some kind of quantum particle doesn't behave as it should on the space ship and uses this as proof that they're in a (slightly) imperfect simulation. When the rest of the crew repeat the experiment, however, the quantum particle behaves normally. Regardless, thecrazy guy kills himself to escape the simulation.

Some other stuff happens after that but the twist at the end was that it really was a simulation (by aliens or something I think) and the aliens just fixed the simulation after the first experiment the crazy guy did.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't involve a quantum particle, but otherwise it sounds very similar to this: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263796/movie-or-tv-episode-where-scientists-go-through-a-successively-less-and-less-pro/263806#263806

Comment: @Rogi - Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, how did the 'crazy guy' kill himself?

Comment: If it's stepping out of the airlock, then definitely "Six Degrees of Freedoms"...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Movie or TV episode where scientists go through a successively less and less probable set of circumstances to finally make first contact](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263796/movie-or-tv-episode-where-scientists-go-through-a-successively-less-and-less-pro)

Comment: @Pete - Our [policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance?noredirect=1&lq=1) is to not mark a Story-ID question as a duplicate unless we have confirmation (from both parties) that they're asking about the same property.

Answer (score 2):

As other have noted, "[Six Degrees of Freedom](https://www.cbr.com/twilight-zones-six-degrees-of-freedom-explained/)", the sixth episode of the first season of the 2019 reboot of *The Twilight Zone*, is a likely match.

> With 180 days left until they reach Mars to colonize, however, the crew has to find a way to work through the torment of knowing what they left behind, wrestling with the thought they could well end up being Earth's last survivors. And so, through music, sex and other distractions, they occupy their minds and recalibrate, with the population of Mars being their new mission. However, as Captain Alexa (DeWanda Wise) thinks they've finally gotten over the disaster and have accepted the inevitable, their chief technician Jerry (Jefferson White) begins to lose his mind, claiming their journey is a conspiracy concocted by NASA.
>
> Jerry's been collecting data secretly on the vessel. Using his engineering skills, he deduces they're not actually heading to Mars -- it's all a simulation. To him, the ship's conditions don't sync up with interstellar travel and he believes this is a test of mental durability and stability. He posits NASA wants to test their minds, pushing them to their limits to see if they'll break under dire circumstances. This actually seems to hold some truth to it, because just as Jerry starts convincing Alexa's crew, there's suddenly a solar flare incoming.
>
> The crew secures themselves, but Jerry, adamant this is a ruse, heads to an airlock and exposes himself to the flare's lethal energies, thinking he'll be taken in by NASA for exposing the fraud. Shockingly, he's burnt to death, disproving his theory and leaving Alexa and company without so much as a body to burn. As the episode winds down, they do successfully land on Mars, regretful Jerry went insane and couldn't be there with them. However, in the final sequence, we come to see Jerry was somewhat correct all along, as the Bradbury was indeed part of a test, only it wasn't monitored by humans, but by an alien species.

[image: Still from the show, showing the crew on their ship]

Answer (score 0):

Probably is not, but the one that reminded me of is dark city
https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0118929/
It's about aliens that simulate a world for humans to experiment on them.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that this would be the correct answer, considering that _Dark City_ focuses on a single protagonist wandering around a city, while the plot described by the OP involves a crew on a space mission.